# Exceeded the virtual memory limit

Tags: plugins, hosting, private

I've launched website a few weeks ago using WP. I've started getting messages from my web host saying "Your website.com web hosting account exceeded one or more of its resources within the last 12 hours. Exceeded the virtual memory limit of 310.4 MB". Is there something configured incorrectly that is causing this?

To explain more, this site is private with user logins using an obox theme. Comments are not enabled. It has been used by two people off and on throughout these weeks. And there are not many plugins. Thanks.

Comment: IS your WP version  4.3?

Comment: I just updated it. Hopefully that can help.

Comment: ooops... i did ask about 4.3 because it had and issue. now please install this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp33423-hotfix/ to avoid future issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to guess how is memory spent in your site. In context of WordPress it will simply obey PHP memory limit and will crash upon reaching it.

Your description sounds more like the total of server memory, which isn't just WP, but everything on server (including web server software, database software, and so on). If that's the case 310 megabytes sounds on a very low end and might be simply insufficient for your site altogether.

Comment: Yeah, the insufficient server memory was one thing that I thought but wasn't sure if that could actually be a possibility. I've never experienced this on other sites I've used WP in. Thanks for your help.